# Precedence of cast operators in php

Tags: php

Precedence isn't very well explained in php see here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

this isn't clear for example:

```
$x = (float)'100'/100;
```

will this first cast '100' to float, then make the division, or divide first, then make the cast?

Comment: You can execute and see what you get.

Comment: From the page you linked: "The following table lists the operators in order of precedence, with the highest-precedence ones at the top. Operators on the same line have equal precedence, in which case associativity decides grouping."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your link https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php already explains, the table is ordered by precedence.

First, you've got in line 3 the type cast (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting), than the 6th line (arithmetic operators).

Your code is equivalent to

```php
$x = ((float)'100') / 100;
```

or

```php
$y = (float)'100';
$x = $y / 100;
```

respectively.

Comment: you are absolutely right, was end of the day for me

Answer (score 0):

According to the table you linked to, type casting has higher precedence (row 3) than multiplication and division operators (row 6). So it's treated as

```
$x = ((float)'100') / 100;
```

It first casts `'100'` to float, then performs the division.